# Is It Possible Define a Custom Excel Style That Preserves Pre-Existing Number Formatting?

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following VBA Code to define a Custom Style named `AlreadyCompleted`. This is to signify that the item in the row is completed.

The code is:

```
Sub DefineAlreadyCompleted()

Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim theNewStyle As Style
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    ' Check to see if Style already exists
    On Error Resume Next
    Set theNewStyle = wb.Styles("AlreadyCompleted")
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    ' If Style Already Exists, Do Nothing
    If Not theNewStyle Is Nothing Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Add New Style
    Set theNewStyle = wb.Styles.Add("AlreadyCompleted")
    
    ' Define the Formatting Properties
    With theNewStyle
        .IncludeNumber = True
        .Font.Strikethrough = True
        .Interior.Color = wb.Styles("Good").Interior.Color
    End With
   
End Sub
```

The table in question has some custom number formatting. The first column houses an ID number in "0-00000-00000" for mat, and columns 5 and 6 contain dates in "m/dd/yyyy" format. When this style is applied, the ID Number reverts to a regular number(`0-12345-67890` becomes `1234567890`) and the dates become strings of numbers (`10/31/2025` becomes `45961`).

Is there any way to change this style to preserve the respective number formatting already used in the columns without having to write a subroutine that goes back and puts it back again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set

```
        .IncludeNumber = False
```

instead of True to not include the number format.

When adding a style through Excel UI, all of the settings are enabled by default:
[image]

Comment: I did that and it worked. When I originally created the style, I didn't even have the `.IncludeNumber` property as part of it. But it would still strip the exisiting Number Formatting. And Since I wasn't using `BasedOn`, would that not make `.IncludeNumber` be `False` by default?

Comment: Excel VBA methods will generally use the same defaults as seen through the Excel UI when performing the corresponding action manually. When adding a style manually, all settings are true by default. So when adding a style through VBA, all settings are also true by default.